# Implicit differentiation from Larson 13.5

Tags: derivatives

Implicit differentiation:
$$\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y^{2}=5$$
I've tried several ways including Wolfram, and the answer is not getting accepted.
This is how I did it so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*I do not know how implicit differentiation has been teached to you; so my naswer may be not the appropriate one.*

Consider a function an implicit function $F(x,y)=0$ and consider each partial derivative $F'_x(x,y)$ and $F'_y(x,y)$. The implicit function theorem leads to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x(x,y) } {F'_y(x,y) }$$ This is derived from the expression of the total derivative $$dF(x,y)=F'_x(x,y) \,dx+F'_y(x,y) \,dy=0$$

Let us apply to

$$F(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y^{2}-5=0$$ So, using the standard derivation steps, $$F'_x(x,y)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$ $$F'_y(x,y)=-\frac{2 x y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}-2 y$$ which then make, after some minor simplifications, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x(x,y) } {F'_y(x,y) }=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2 y \left((x^2+y^2)^2+x)\right)}$$ which is exactly what your image shows.

Comment: Nice, if a bit complicated. I think it makes everything a lot cleaner here if we multiply by $x^2+y^2$ to clear all fractions and *then* move everything over to the LHS, but that is perhaps just me abhorrence toward differentiating fractions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. You are totally correct, for sure. I just tried to stay as close as possible to the orginal problem.

Comment: I know that "Thanks" is not allowed, it says right here while I am typing this, but how else do I express my appreciation? I am new here. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @JennyKay. Be sure that you are very welcome ! And welcome to the this fantastic site !!

Comment: @JennyKay haha, I find that Math.SE is *much* less restrictive on comments than other SE sites I follow. A few people here and there might complain about a comment of appreciation, but I love getting them, and I feel the same is true of most users. In fact, many people will delete their posts the second someone answers their homework question through a comment. The fact that you showed work, consulted Wolfram Alpha, cited the problem, *and* showed gratitude is STELLAR in my book.

Comment: @JennyKay on that note, given how much you seem to appreciate the help you've received, I'd invite you to consider helping others out on this site once you've learned a topic yourself. It's good practice for you and it helps others... A win-win! If you do choose to answer questions, don't be afraid if you don't get upvoted or even get downvoted at first... Often this is just a lack of understanding when it comes to formatting answers, and not a lack of understanding the content. If you have any questions on that feel free to ask me! Nevertheless, even if you just ask questions, I hope (cntd)

Comment: @JennyKay (cntd) you find the rest of your experience with Math.SE enjoyable :)

Comment: Thank you so much, guys. Thank you, @ClaudeLeibovici, for such a thorough computation. And yes, Brevan, I will try to help others, and although I believe my math skills at this stage could be defined as "germination", I also think that helping others helps to retain the existing knowledge  ...I will be banned for saying "thanks" multple times. :)